# Write out from random sample

Tags: python, random

I have a 30 n random sample from a list which I write to a file.

I would rather like to tag the lines that went to the sample by writing in the end "in_sample" or "not_in_sample".

Now it looks like this:

```
mysample=random.sample(list, 30)
for i in mysample:
    out.write("%s\n" % (i))
```

I only write out lines from the sample but I would want the file to look like this:

```
line 1 in_sample

line 2 not_in_sample

line 3 in_sample

line 4 not_in_sample
```

The file looked the same before but without the last column.

Am I clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do that is to **sample on your list indexes** instead of on its content.

For example, if your list is called `lst`:

```
indexes_samples = sorted(random.sample(range(len(lst)), 30))

for i in indexes_samples:
    lst[i]  # do what you want
```

Or maybe I think you might want to do something like:

```
idx = sorted(random.sample(range(len(lst)), 30))

j = 0
for i,num in enumerate(lst):
    if j <= len(idx) and i == idx[j]:
        msg = 'line {} in sample'
        j += 1
    else:
        msg = 'line {} not in sample'

    print(msg.format(num))   # out.write() or whatever
```

Comment: @AWE: You're welcome! I restored those 2 lines from the old edit :)

Answer (score 1):

```
my_sample = set(random.sample(my_list, 30))
for i, item in enumerate(my_list, 1):
    out.write('line {0} {1}\n'.format(i, ('not_in_sample', 'in_sample')[item in my_sample]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mysample=random.sample(list, 30)
for i in range(1:31)
    if i in mysample:
        out.write("line %s\n in_sample" % (i))
    else:
        out.write("line %s\n not_in_sample" % (i))
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your samples in a set, iterate from 1 to your maximum population value, and use containment testing to see if the current iteration is in the set.